# Is it possible on AWS to enforce MFA on group level (e.g. for all with administrator rights)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

Is it possible to create an IAM rule or an SCP (organization rule) to enforce MFA for all users in a certain group or with certain rights (e.g. administrators or power user)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you can attach a deny portion to any policy or create a deny policy and attach it to any group.

For example you have "Administrators" group that has many roles added as well as "MultifactorAuthForce" policy:

[image]

Example of "MultifactorAuthForce":

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAllWithoutMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Update:**
Just tested it on my account and the policy works. Created an account without MFA, added password and assigned to the group above. When logged as that user I was denied all actions on all resources. After, I added MFA to the user and logged in again. I was able to see the resources.